# SSIS Dynamic expression

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I am trying to pass table name and parameter name dynamic to expression task which is getting failed.

[image]

My Expression is like

```
@[User::vSQLCommand] ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM"+  @[User::ExtractFileStageTableName] +" WHERE"+ 
@[User::IsNotNullColumnName]+"   IS NULL AND"+  @[User::IsNotNullColumnName]   +"=''"
```

This is simple SQL query being like

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lnd.ANC_LND_ItemOverride WHERE Comments IS NULL OR Comments = ''
```

but unable to achieve in expression. Any help please

**RESOLUTION:** 
As I am not still sure why dynamic values are not working in expression task. I have used Script Task and could achieve results.

Comment: What is the error message being reported from the expression editor?

Answer (score 2):

While we're waiting for the exact error, mentally parsing the expression I think you need spaces in there for it to be valid SQL. Also, you should use `OR` operator instead of `AND`:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +  @[User::ExtractFileStageTableName] + " WHERE " + 
@[User::IsNotNullColumnName]+"   IS NULL OR "+  @[User::IsNotNullColumnName]   +" = ''"
```

The supplied SQL text had `FROM` and `WHERE` butting up against the next property in the expression.

From the comments, Shweta indicates that they can't see `@[User::IsNotNullColumnName]`  If you're using SQL Server 2005 and maybe 2008/2008R2 development tools, the default behavior is that an SSIS variable will be created at the scope where the cursor has focus. Assuming your package has a Foreach Enumerator sitting in the control flow, that Foreach container has an Execute SQL Task in it and the Execute SQL Task is currently selected, a variable will be created that only has scope while that task is executing. Referencing that variable in the Foreach Loop container or the package will fail as the variable is out of scope.

The far more common reason the expression editor will report errors with variable names is that they are case sensitive. Thus @[User::IsNotNullColumnName] is not the same as @[User::IsNotNullColumnname] or even the ever so fun @[User::IsNotNullColumName]

Comment: I tried above but still cant see @[User::IsNotNullColumnName]

Comment: ANy other possibility that a variable may miss from foreach loop ?

Comment: @ShwetaReddy It will be more clear if you provide more information about the foreach loop container source and variable mapping. (feel free to add more screenshots :) )

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for your reply., yet I have removed expression task and done it in script task and could achieve desired results.